# Javascript slider to change variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

What I've got so far up on codepen:

http://codepen.io/Shane24/pen/cEGsb

I need to save the values that appear in the input boxes when you move the sliders into variables.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulties with? This is really simple. Please don't just ask for people to write the code for you http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Just store 3 global variables in JavaScript and add listeners to the sliders to change those values and use `clearRect` followed by a redrawing of the canvas and you're all set. Should be peanuts really. Use your imagination :)

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm not asking you to write it? I'm having difficulties getting the numbers that appear in the input box saved into variables which update dynamically using the sliders

Comment: @Allendar Thanks. Not sure how to add a listener but I'll give it a go. Appreciated!

Comment: @Shane A good learning school is to look in to the Development version of jQuery. I'm not promoting to "use" jQuery here, but it's source code has tons of cool raw JavaScript gems. Look into jQuery's `change()` functionality; http://api.jquery.com/change/ Good luck!

Comment: @Shane `document.getElementById('amount1').value` will give you the value on the first textfield

Comment: Are you just trying to change the canvas as the user modifies the sliders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer to the question is that you can set your variables from the slider's handlers

```
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $('amount1').val( ui.value );
    // This is the value that you just dragged the slider to, there it is,
    // in a variable
    x = ui.value;
  }
```

Without knowing what you needed [I whipped up an example that should show you a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uoIAc) where I extract the values from the sliders and apply it to the color of the circle in the canvas. This code works with the HTML you posted initially

```
function drawOnCanvas () {
   var rgb =[
       $('#slider-1').slider("value"),
       $('#slider-2').slider("value"),
       $('#slider-3').slider("value")
   ];
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   var color = "rgb("+ rgb.join(',') + ")" ;
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.fill();
}

function createSlider(slider, boundTextField) {
   slider.slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 255,
      value: 0,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        boundTextField.val( ui.value );
        drawOnCanvas();
      }
  })
}

$(function() {
    createSlider($( "#slider-1" ), $( "#amount1" ));
    createSlider($( "#slider-2" ), $( "#amount2" ));
    createSlider($( "#slider-3" ), $( "#amount3" ));    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a console output of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null"

Comment: I added the button <input type="button" id="amount1" /> and added var textfield = document.getElementById('amount1');
var value = textfield.value;
document.write(value); to my js. However the document.write prints nothing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also I have  
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
        z = ui.value;
        $( "#amount1" ).val( ui.value );
      } - Is that even doing anything? As you can see, my javascript is not the best...

Comment: Don't ever use `document.write`, what you were doing wrong is that you were executing the code before the HTML was parsed. That last snipper is setting the value in the text field. Hopefully my new answer will help you, but you need to read up a lot more and ask more detailed questions that show what you have tried. This question  did not show what you've tried, because you didn't even describe what you wanted (Setting variables doesn't count)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that about document.write. That's a huge help. To give you some context, I have a pair of headphones drawn in HTML5 canvas. I currently have the functionality for the user to rotate the headphones, but I needed to be able to allow the user to also change the colour via a slider. I decided to start small with the circle. I'm new to javascript, and stack overflow, so apologies if I wasn't clear, or if it was too simple a question to be asking. I greatly appreciate your help. Thanks so much! The new example is exactly the functionality I was looking for.